# Change of display page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I bought an application development training in c# with xamarin.forms and I work on visual studio 2022.

I have made good progress in the training and I display the content on my phone when I debug I use my phone instead of 'an emulator recently created a second file to add an application page which is the menu I followed the same steps but when I debug it always shows me the first page and therefore I cannot see the result of my second step (I want to remember that the file I opened is xaml content.)

The question is the following : how to display another file on an emulator or phone for example.

please answer. I really need help

Comment: You'll need to show at least some of your code and explain how you've set up navigation and how you've registered the second view. I would also go over the training again and make sure you've followed the instructions completely; make sure you read all the information - happens all the time.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  We can't help you if you don't show us what you are doing.

Comment: I don't know what your course covered but here is the official **Microsoft Xamarin** page that explains [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) and how to change pages